# What is (roughly) the net charge of the DNA in an average human cell?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology, dna, electrophysiology

I was wondering about what general range for the net charge of DNA in human cells is in Coulombs.  I imagine that kind of thing would be hard to measure but could be approximately calculated/estimated.  Could you approximate it by taking the average number of base pairs in the human genome and multiplying it by the charge of a phosphate group?  Would you have to multiply by two as well because there are two phosphate groups attached to each base pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That reasoning seems to work for Harvard's [bionumbers database](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/bionumber.aspx?id=103784&ver=5&trm=Charge%20Dna&org=). They use a charge of -2 per base pair, and then estimate the linear charge density as 2e / 0.34 nm, where 0.34 nm is the length of a base pair. There are approximately [3.08 billion base pairs](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/bionumber.aspx?id=101484&ver=22&trm=base%20pairs%20human%20genome&org=) in the human genome, so you could run the same calculation: $2e \cdot 3.08 \cdot 10^9 = 9.86 \cdot 10^{-10} C$.